# Method to Send Automatic Report in Webhosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, scheduled-tasks, web-hosting

I have web project that created in Visual Studio 2010 and use SQL Server 2008 R2 for database,
Commonly i use SQL Server Agent to send report (from SQL database) to my client email, and now i want to move my application to other web hosting. My question is there any method to generate report and send to email automatically by schedule in web hosting?

Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Scheduling tasks in a web project is possible using the [Revalee](http://revalee.sageanalytic.com) open source project.

Revalee is a service that allows you to schedule web callbacks to your web application. In your case, you would schedule a callback that would generate your report and send emails automatically. Revalee works very well with tasks that are discrete transactional actions, like updating a database value or sending an automated email message (read: not long running). The code to generate your report and send the emails would reside within your web app. More specifically, on a target web page that Revalee would call at your scheduled time. When your application launches for the very first time, then you would schedule the first web callback. When your application is called back to generate the report, then you would schedule the next callback.

To use Revalee, you would:

1. Install the Revalee Service, a Windows Service, on your server. The Windows Service is available in the source code (which you would compile yourself) or in a precompiled version available at the [Revalee website](http://revalee.sageanalytic.com) (above).
2. Use the Revalee client library in your Visual Studio project. The client library is available in the source code (which, again, you would compile yourself) or in a precompiled version available via [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Revalee.Client/).
3. You would register a future callback (for example, at a specific time) when your application launches via the `ScheduleMidnightCallback()` method (see below).

   ```
   private DateTimeOffet? previousCallbackTime = null;

   private void ScheduleMidnightCallback()
   {
       // Schedule your callback for midnight tomorrow
       var tomorrow = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1.0);
       var callbackTime = new DateTimeOffset(tomorrow.Year, 
                                             tomorrow.Month, 
                                             tomorrow.Day, 
                                             0,    // Hour 
                                             0,    // Minute 
                                             0,    // Second 
                                             tomorrow.Offset);

       // Your web service's Uri, including any query string parameters your app might need
       Uri callbackUrl = new Uri("http://yourwebapp.com/Callback.aspx");

       // Register the callback request with the Revalee service
       RevaleeRegistrar.ScheduleCallback(callbackTime, callbackUrl);

       previousCallbackTime = callbackTime;
   }
   ```
4. When the web scheduled task activates and calls your application back, you perform whatever action you need to do at midnight *and* you schedule the next callback too. You do this by adding the following method call (`CallbackMonitor()`) to your `Callback.aspx` page handler.

   ```
   private DateTimeOffset? mostRecentCallback = null;

   private void CallbackMonitor()
   {
       var midnight = new DateTimeOffset(DateTimeOffset.Now.Year, 
                                         DateTimeOffset.Now.Month, 
                                         DateTimeOffset.Now.Day, 
                                         0,              // Hour 
                                         0,              // Minute 
                                         0,              // Second 
                                         DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset);

       if (!mostRecentCallback.HasValue 
           || mostRecentCallback.Value < midnight)
       {
           mostRecentCallback = midnight;

           // Perform your report generation & send email-related tasks
           // ...do your work here...

           // Schedule subsequent callback
           ScheduleMidnightCallback();
       }
   }
   ```

I hope this helps.

One last thing: Revalee does have an ASP.NET MVC specific library as well, in case you are migrating your web application from ASP.NET to ASP.NET MVC.

<sub>**Disclaimer:** I was one of the developers involved with the Revalee project. To be clear, however, Revalee is free, open source software. The source code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/SageAnalytic/Revalee).</sub>